# XSLT count with multiple conditions from different levels in hierarchy

Tags: xslt

I have a line in an.xsl file that counts how many objects have a Pass property equal to true:

```
<xsl:variable name='NumPass' select='count(MyClass/MyContainer/MyObject/Pass[normalize-space(text())="true"])' />
```

I need to add a 2nd condition: MyContainer.Valid = true

So I want count to only include passes from valid containers. How do I modify the statement to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know how is your input xml, but have you tried this?

```
<xsl:variable name='NumPass' select='count(MyClass/MyContainer[Valid='true']/MyObject/Pass[normalize-space(text())="true"])' />
```

I cant comment because of reputation, but you should put your input xml.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Maybe the condition has to go with double quotes Valid="true". I always use single quote but maybe depends on processor.